# WP ajax response is empty for $_POST value

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, function

I am trying to echo the posted value of an input field via WP ajax, but it keeps returning empty (i.e. no $_POST content), why? If I try to echo 'test', it works.

functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'ajx_action_subscriber');
function ajx_action_subscriber() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#subscribe-submit', function() {

            var subscribe_email = $('#footer-email').val();

            $('#subscribe-confirmation').html('Registering');

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                type : 'post',
                data : {action:'subscribe_user', subscribe_email:subscribe_email},
                success : function( response ) {
                    $('#subscribe-confirmation').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_subscribe_user', 'subscribe_user');
function subscribe_user() {
    echo $_POST['subscribe_email'];
    // echo 'test'; // works successfully ?!!?
    die();
}
```

Comment: If it did not receive `action:'subscribe_user'` correctly, there would be no reason why it would execute your function in the first place - so POST “in general” must apparently be working. The most logical conclusion would then be, that you did send an _empty_ value for `subscribe_email`. Use your browser dev tools to first of all verify (or disprove) that, inspect the request in the network panel.

Comment: in fact I needed to add a second action "nopriv" to make it work: add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_subscribe_user', 'subscribe_user');